# Как сделать split по строкам?

Tags: c#

Правильной ли является часть кода?

```
     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] tablica = line.Split('\n');

        }
```

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В теории достаточно

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(
    new[] { Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.None
);
```

где `Environment.NewLine` - берет системный разделитель для линий.

Если вы бес понятия какой тип разделителя в тексте и хочется попытаться всё обработать, то можно попробовать:

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(
    new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.None
);
```

---

А если хотите читать построчно, то, возможно, стоит воспользоваться `StringReader` и методом `ReadLine()`. Примерно:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(input)) {
    string line;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Так автор вроде и так построчно считывает

Comment: @tym32167 ммм. ну значит его конструкция со сплитом бессмысленна